# Sorting data in RAM

Tags: c++, embedded

Suppose you are in an embedded environment and you have, oh, 1MB of RAM to play with. Now let's pretend you have a JSON based file management system in which each file produced by the device (let's say its metadata files) is entered into this (or these) JSON files. You let this device do whatever it does and a month later it comes back with 10,000 files and entries stored into the file system and JSON file. Each entry consumed around 200 bytes, so you have 10,000 * 200 = 2MB. Now you want to sort all those files by some piece of data, let's say by file name, which is 100 bytes each.

In order to sort, maybe alphabetically, do you need to load all 10,000 file names into RAM at once, or are there sequential ways to sort this kind of data? Maybe by first sorting it into subfiles and then sorting those files further? Is it even possible?

This a C++ environment.

Comment: What is the actual final result supposed to be? What is the format of the sorted results and where do they need to be stored?

Comment: A vector of sorted file names that can be sent somewhere.. maybe along a wire, maybe to another module.

Answer (score 1):

> In order to sort, maybe alphabetically, do you need to load all 10,000 file names into RAM at once,…

No, you do not.

> … or are there sequential ways to sort this kind of data?

Of course ways exist to sort external data exist, although they are not necessarily “sequential.” Sorting data that is not all in main memory at once is called [external sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting).

> Maybe by first sorting it into subfiles and then sorting those files further?

Stack Overflow is for answering specific questions or problems. Whether algorithms exist and what they are called are specific questions, so I have answered those. What the algorithms are and what their properties and benefits are is a general question, so you should do further research on your own regarding them.

> Is it even possible?

Yes.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access them in a specific order, it might be a good idea to just store them in this way on the file system in the first place.
As @Eric mentioned, this is not a specific question. You should just improve your C/C++ skills in order to answer these questions for yourself. There are a lot of free resources in the web.